# Unknown error: Function eregi_replace()

Tags: theming, views

i am using pressflow 6.25
 there is a flie views-view-field--events--block--field-date-value.tpl.php  in template theme directory

in line 5

```
$create_date = explode(' ',eregi_replace('<[^>]*>','', $output));
```

in my web site 
show this error
Unknown error: Function eregi_replace() is deprecated in include() (line 5 of C:\xampp\htdocs\fiddle\sites\all\themes\sttheme\fiddle\templates\views-view-field--events--block--field-date-value.tpl.php).
how can i solve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

There may be a problem with the PHP version.

See [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi-replace.php)

> This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this
>   feature is highly discouraged.

Comment: i change eregi_replace with preg_replace() but show this warning Warning: preg_replace() [<a href='function.preg-replace'>function.preg-replace</a>]: Unknown modifier ']' in include() (line 5 of C:\xampp\htdocs\fiddle\sites\all\themes\sttheme\fiddle\templates\views-view-field--events--block--field-date-value.tpl.php).

Comment: Try to add escaping characters in your `preg_replace` code or paste your source code here so that someone can help.

Comment: $create_date = explode(' ',preg_replace('<[^>]*>','', $output));

  echo date('d',strtotime($create_date[0])) . '/' . date('m',strtotime($create_date[0]));